# Can my questions be solved on this site? If not where else can I ask?

Tags: discussion, support, unanswered-questions

I need to solve a series of computations in the question [Is there a way we can compute my sum involving `subsets` more efficiently?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/40036/is-there-a-way-we-can-compute-my-sum-involving-subsets-more-efficiently).

I placed a 50 point bounty but no one was able to answer.

If I place a 100 bounty I will lose all my points and won’t be able to place another bounty for future updates questions?

Is my question possible to answer? Is there ways to improve it?

- Edit: A mod stated that my notation is confusing. Can someone point out examples and state a better way of writing the notations so I can make it clearer.

Comment: I think that your question is on-topic on this site. I guess that it has not received much attention because of the notation since it might be a little bit confusing. Maybe try to rewrite in a clearer way.

Comment: @nicoguaro I tried to [rewrite](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/40036/is-there-a-way-we-can-compute-my-sum-involving-subsets-more-efficiently) it in a better way but this is the best I could do? Would you say it's better?

Comment: @Arbuja The notation can definitely be improved. Why do you need to define $A$ in your question, for instance? And $F$ (with a spurious index) rather than $\Delta F$ directly? Is $\Delta F$ a set or a multiset? Why isn't the example worked out till the end?

Comment: @Fredrico Poloni - The reason I need $F_t$ is because $A$ is countably infinite. You need to take restrict $A$ to a finite set then find $d$. 
- $\Delta F$ is a multi-set. - I further worked out the example as requested.

Answer (score 3):

Please, follow nicoguaro's advice on improving a bit of clarity on this question, particularly with notation.

This question is certainly on-topic and of great interest (see voting) for the Computational Science SE. It probably could be answered, it depends on whether someone with this experience is going to see it. Some people don't come here every day, so I would give it a chance.

I placed my bounty on it now as well, but your edits/clarifications might be more important than the bounty itself.